# Split up a dataframe by number of NAs in each row

Tags: r, dataframe, split, na

Consider a dataframe made up of thousand rows and columns that inclues several *NA*s. I'd like to split this dataframe up into smaller ones based on the number of *NA*s in each row. All rows that contain the same number of *NA*s, if there is any, should be in the same group. The new data frames are then saved separately.

```
> DF
ID  C1 C2 C3 C4 C5
aa  12 13 10 NA 12 
ff  12 NA NA 23 13
ee  67 23 NA NA 21
jj  31 14 NA 41 11
ss  NA 15 11 12 11
```

The desired output will be:

```
> DF_chunk_1
ID  C1 C2 C3 C4 C5
aa  12 13 10 NA 12
jj  31 14 NA 41 11
ss  NA 15 11 12 11

> DF_chunk_2
ID  C1 C2 C3 C4 C5
ff  12 NA NA 23 13
ee  67 23 NA NA 21
```

I appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: A pointer might be to use the fact that `sum(is.na(x))` will return the amount of `NA`s in a column `x`. This could also be used for rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this following useful comments. You can `split()` and use `apply()` to build a group:

```
#Code
new <- split(DF,apply(DF[,-1],1,function(x)sum(is.na(x))))
```

Output:

```
$`1`
  ID C1 C2 C3 C4 C5
1 aa 12 13 10 NA 12
4 jj 31 14 NA 41 11
5 ss NA 15 11 12 11

$`2`
  ID C1 C2 C3 C4 C5
2 ff 12 NA NA 23 13
3 ee 67 23 NA NA 21
```

A more practical way (Many thanks and credits to **@RuiBarradas**):

```
#Code2
new <- split(DF, rowSums(is.na(DF[-1])))
```

Same output.

Comment: Beat me by seconds but I use `split(DF, rowSums(is.na(DF[-1])))`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas It is a great suggestion and more practical, I will add that with credit to you!

Comment: @Duck The solution works nicely but, what if I want to get those chunks as separate data frames rather than elements of a list and then removing columns containing `NA`s

Comment: @davide_Cent First do this `names(new)<-paste0('dfchunck_',names(new))` then `new <- lapply(new, function(x) {x<-x[,-which(apply(x,2,function(x)sum(is.na(x)))>0)]})` and finally `list2env(new,envir = .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: @Duck that was great! the only condition that it cannot be coverded is when there are rows in the original `DF` without any `NA`, so the final data `dfchunk_` from those rows would be an empty data frame! Is it something can be managed inside of the suggested code?

Comment: @davide_Cent In that case you would have a group 0 and data would be on there!

Comment: @Duck true! I got the `dfchunk_0` but it is empty. A data frame including the correct number of observation and zero variables which is not actually fit with this fact that there are some rows with no `NA` record in the reference `DF`.

Comment: @davide_Cent In code in comments try this change `sum(is.na(x)))>=0`

Comment: @davide_Cent or this `lapply(new, function(x) {x<-x[,-which(apply(x,2,function(x)!is.na(sum(x)))]})`

Comment: @Duck the first alternative `>=0` comes out with zero variable for all chunks and the last one gives an error:  `Error in sum(x) : invalid 'type' (character) of argument `

Comment: @davide_Cent All variables must be numeric, you must have a character!

Comment: @Duck they are but, the actual data frame includes the first two columns which are different (Factor and level), the rest of the thousand variables are numeric. Should I convert them some how into the numeric character or it would be managable through the currect code since those two columns specify identifiers and not variable values.

Comment: @davide_Cent try this `lapply(new, function(x) {x<-x[,-which(apply(x[-c(1,2)],2,function(x)!is.na(sum(x)))]})`

Comment: @Duck The error logically disappeared now. The last code does not get the columns including NAs out from the data frames, so the finall chunks have all the same numbers as variables. I get all rows divided into chunks based on the NAs counts but they have still remained. looks like this`!is.na` does not make sense for him which cannot be true. I do appreciate your help